# Can only counterexamples disprove conditional statements

Tags: logic, soft-question

Consider the statement "If $\sum x_n$ converges conditionally and every $x_n$ contains no digit 2 in its decimal expansion then $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely". It is almost certainly false, containing a digit 2 is irrelevant from converging absolutely. Yet it seems quite difficult/awkward to come up with a counter example. Please don't give one, its besides the point of this question. Is there any logical argument that disproves a conditional statement like this without having to provide an example?

Something to the effect of  "Property $X$ is irrelevant to Property $Y$ thus $X \nRightarrow Y $". Traditionally we're taught that this line of reasoning is cardinal sin so I am anticipating a fat "NO".

Comment: How would you know to it is "irrelevant" without a counterexample?

Comment: In this particular case you could say that Leibniz criterion does not care about the decimal expansion and you get an easy counterexample. But in general the whole point is that we would like to show that it is indeed "irrelevant".

Answer (score 1):

The point is: If the claim is false and a counter example exists, then there are often *many* counter examples or even infinitely many (which applies IMO to your example).

This means that any generic proof will be a superset of (infinitely) many explicit counter examples.  And such "generic" counter examples are usually harder to find than a specific one; that's the reason why you'll typically see specific counterexamples.  The smaller the set is that the generic proof encompasses, the harder it is usually to write and to understand.  Yet trying some generic proof can lead you to (more) specific counter examples, or to more refined versions of the proposition.

Moreover, "conditional convergence" is a rather technical term from inifnite series, which means that re-ordering the sequence under consideration might change its convergence behavior or value.  So I am not shure if you confused "conditional statement" with "conditional convergence"?  "Conditional convergence" basically means "convergent but not absolutely convergent".

Comment: To clarify, I did mean conditional convergence in the example statement, but used conditional statement to describe $A\implies B$. Thanks for your interesting answer.

Comment: @aristotlefromgreece Just to make sure your trouble is with counterexamples rather than the underlying general logic: how would you give a counterexample to a statement of the form $A\implies B?$